# Verify Binary Tree Using Given Traversal

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

Is it possible to identify sequences for which no binary tree exists given two traversals (example: an in order and post order traversal)?

I understand that the last element of a post order traversal, or the first element of a pre order traversal, is the root of the tree. Using basic facts like that, is it possible to test these arrays without actually building a tree and find out if they produce the same tree?

I have an algorithm already that can build a tree out of these two sequences (in- and post-), but I don't want to have to run the algorithm if there is a way to test the arrays beforehand. It would save a lot of time instead of running the algorithm and finding out at the end.

Note: This does NOT have to be a binary search tree. A binary tree will suffice.

Comment: I don't understand - can't any sequence be stored in a binary tree?

Comment: Yes, but if you are given an in order and post order traversal as your two sequences, how can you tell if they come from the same tree?

Comment: So much clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm starting again since the question is a little different than I thought. Given an inorder and postorder traversal can you find if there is a tree that can generate them both?

Lets consider this tree:

```
     a
   /   \
  b     e
 / \   / \
c   d f   g
```

The traversals are:

```
inorder:    CBDAFEG
postorder:  CDBFGEA
```

Now some observations:

a. The last node in postorder is always the root node.

b  If you know the root node you can split an inorder traversal into left-traversal, root, right-traversal.

So you can without creating a tree run a recursive algorithm that determines if they can be generated by the same tree.

Like this:

Given Io and Po as the two traverals,

If they are different lengths then there is no tree in common.

If the same length then:

1. Take the last node of Po - call it R
2. Find R in Io. If not found there is no tree in common.
3. R determines the boundaries of the left and right sub tree, so split Io and Po based on the position of R in Io:

   CBD A FEG

   CDB FEG A

(e.g. once you know that the left sub tree has to be 3 nodes long, and the right sig tree is also 3 nodes long, you can split Po the same way also )

4. Call this algorithm recursively on the left and right subtrees.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in the general case since you can't determine the structure of a tree just from the traversal. That is there are many trees that generate the same traversal.

For example here are two trees with the same in-order traversal.

```
  A                       A
 / \                     /
B   C                   B
                       /
                      C
```

But their post order traversals are different. So its impossible to say given in-order and post-order traversals if the same tree was used to generate them.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. It is possible to construct a binary tree given an in-order and post-order traversal. See: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/if-you-are-given-two-traversal-sequences-can-you-construct-the-binary-tree/

I'm just trying to find out if it's possible to verify before actually constructing the tree.

Comment: That is a different question. Its possible to determine if an in-order and post-order sequence have a tree that generates them in common. But the converse is not true - given in-order and post-order traversals you can't guarantee that the same tree was used to generate them.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean now. That is what I am looking to find out. Since you cannot guarantee the same tree was used to generate the two traversals, is there some way to identify sequences for which the tree is not the same? Right now I have a program which, given two sequences that ARE produced by the same tree, can reconstruct that tree. However, if these two sequences do not produce the same tree, I'd like to avoid the whole attempt at reconstruction to save time. Is that possible? Or is it easier to simply attempt the reconstruction and find out at the end?